# R Functions: Print Warning Only on First Call of Function

Tags: r, function, warnings

So I'm trying to write a function that prints an error message, but *only on the first time the user calls the function*.  If they open R, load the library, and call the function, it will print a warning message.  If they call the function again, it will not print this warning message.  If they close R and do the same process, it will print the warning message for the first call and not on the second. I understand the idea of the basic warning() function in R, but I don't see any documentation in the help file for this kind of condition.  Does anyone know of a function or a condition that could be used with the warning() function that would be able to solve this?  Thanks! I am working on a project where the professor in charge needs this for some sort of copyright thing and he wants it to be this way.

Comment: Why do you want to do this.  If you explain your reasoning we might be able to suggest a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Dason in my case, I want to display a message *just* to make sure the user is aware of something (that they almost certainly would be, but which would be bad if they weren't). Hence I don't want to badger them about it (just let them know once)

Answer (score 9):

One package that does this is `quantmod`. When you use the `getSymbols` function, it warns you about the upcoming change to the defaults. It does so using `options`.

```
"getSymbols" <- function(Symbols=NULL,...) {
  if(getOption("getSymbols.warning4.0",TRUE)) {
    # transition message for 0.4-0 to 0.5-0
    message(paste(
            '    As of 0.4-0,',sQuote('getSymbols'),'uses env=parent.frame() and\n',
            'auto.assign=TRUE by default.\n\n',
            'This  behavior  will be  phased out in 0.5-0  when the call  will\n',
            'default to use auto.assign=FALSE. getOption("getSymbols.env") and \n',
            'getOptions("getSymbols.auto.assign") are now checked for alternate defaults\n\n',
            'This message is shown once per session and may be disabled by setting \n',
            'options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE). See ?getSymbol for more details'))
    options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE) 
  }
  #rest of function....
}
```

So they check for an option named "getSymbols.warning4.0" and default to TRUE if not found. Then if it's not found, they display a message (you may display a warning) and then set that option to FALSE so the message will not display next time.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of packages have messages that popup and since there is a mechanism for detecting second efforts at loading futher calls to `library` or `require` are silently ignored. They often are using `.onLoad(libname, pkgname)`. See

```
?.onLoad
```